# LTS upgrade fails: the daemon crashed mid transaction

Tags: do-release-upgrade

In the middle middle of doing a `do-release-upgrade` of current LTS versions, it crashed at 36% of installing packages. The last messages were:

```
proc: bad value for 'hidepid'
the daemon crashed mid-transaction
```

How can I know more about it, and how can I fix it and finish the upgrade ?

Update:
Before that there were many lines of: `Installing packages`

And near the beginning:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packagekit-tools:
packagekit-tools depends on packagekit (= 1.2.5-2ubuntu2); however:
Package packagekit is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package packagekit-tools (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

If I try to do it again:

```
# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

So the install at least partially worked (reboot failed on the latest kernel but worked with the previous one). But on login it says:

```
805 updates can be applied immediately.
30 of these updates are standard security updates.
```

I first did `aptitude install packagekit` and then `aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade && reboot` and it seems to have worked: clean boot, latest version, latest kernel.

Comment: can you run 'do-release-upgrade' again? Can you give more details with output from *before* these two?

Comment: I updated the post after reading your comment. It seems to work now